# Error: spawn flutter ENOENT in flutter build_runner

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, build-runner

The project is the flutter default app and on macOS when I try to run build runner using (command+shift+b) I face this error on output:

Running `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`
Current working folder: `/Users/saeed/Documents/programming/Projects/flutter_bloc_test`
Error: spawn flutter ENOENT